# how to run a gwt servlet automatically in some particular time interval?

Tags: gwt, servlets, scheduling

Please help me about this issue...

In my application i have calender where user can set the events for particular day..
this event info is store in database....
now i want my application to automatically send an email to that user on that assigned day....

Comment: Can you be more specific? Some example please!!!!!!!!

Comment: hi i have added more specific info abt my issue...pls give ur views..thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explititly need the Quartz API for such a simple timer task. For this [java.util.TimerTask](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) is perfectly suitable.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers..using your guidelines i have understood how to achieve this functionality...instead of using Quartz API i can directly use the TimerTask...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use scheduler(quartz).Most of the applications are using that.Particularly for sending mails.

http://www.roseindia.net/quartz/index.shtml

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

https://quartz.dev.java.net/

You can schedule the scheduler to do some action in particular time interval.

Comment: Have a look at this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654376/how-can-send-email-on-specific-day-without-running-my-gwt-servlet

Comment: I won't call roseindia.net a reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet is running on the back-end. So all you need is to create an endless loop which is regulary checking if an email needs to be send out.

Something like this:

```
public void run()
{
 isRunning = true;
 while (isRunning)
 {
  performSomething();

 try
 {
  Thread.sleep(someInterval);
 }
 catch (InterruptedException e)
 {
  isRunning = false;
 }
```

}

Where the performSomething(); method is a synchornized method:

```
public synchronized void performSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using cron jobs, you can call URLs with cron job which can be your servlet that handle the logic.