# How can send email on specific day without running my GWT servlet?

Tags: gwt

In my application user can add there reminder for the specific day and reminder will be   send  to there email address ....

but how can i send there reminder on that day ...

please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this on the server side, which means you won't be using GWT.  You need to look into the scheduling capabilities of whatever server platform you are running on - cron jobs on unix, scheduled tasks on windows, etc.  Also, your servlet container might have some scheduling capabilities as well.  We can't really help you without knowing more.

What server platform are you developing on?  GWT is a client side technology, so that's not going to help.  Are you running a J2EE server, a simple servlet container?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a servlet; use a task scheduled by the OS or [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) and just call a POJO.

Answer (score 0):

A cron job would ideal for this type of task